# How to only keep the regression coefficients of the key treatment variables in my regression output?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, stata, stata-macros

I want to keep only the regression coefficients of the treatment variables in my regression output. How do I achieve this? I have tried quite a few versions of the code below, but in every iteration, the output comes with all the controls and year-fixed effects.

```
local dep_vars "Violent_std Property_std Property2_std Murder_std Manslaughter_std Rape_std Robbery_std Assault_std Burglary_std Larceny_std Vehcile_Theft_std Other_Assault_std Arson_std Stolen_Property_std Vandalism_std All_Drug_Abuse_std Embezzlement_std Weapons_std Prostitution_std DUI_std Disorderly_std Fraud_std Forgery_std "

local treat_vars "Minor13 Minor49 Minor1020 Major13 Major49 Major1020"

local indep_vars "L1.Total_Crime_std Black_Prop_std Labor_Force_std Unemp_Rate_std Tot_Establishments_std Avg_Monthly_Wage_std"

local i = 1
foreach dep_var in `dep_vars' {
qui xtreg `dep_var' `treat_vars' `indep_vars' i.year, fe vce(cluster fips)
estimates store HurrReg`i'
local i = `i' + 1
}


esttab HurrReg1, cells(b(star fmt(3)) se(par fmt(2))) ///
keep (`treat_vars') ///
stats(N r2 r2_a p, labels("Observations" "R-square" "Adjusted R-square" "Model Significance")) ///
title("Regression Results")
```

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1739319-how-to-only-keep-the-regression-coefficients-of-the-key-treatment-variables-in-my-regression-output